# How to reduce the number of requests in React Navigation TopTabNavigator using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-top-tabs

i'm pretty new on React Native and currently i am developing an app using expo. I am using `TopTabNavigator` from react navigation 6 and i don't understand how to reduce the no of the requests. Basically, whenever i hit a certain tab the request is made. (because the component is recreated - even if i come back on previous tab which is the same, no data modified). I tried to use `useFocusEffect` from react navigation but it does not work as i expected. Maybe i should make the requests in the `ProfileTabsScreen` and pass the data via props to the particular tabs?

MAIN COMPONENT

```
const ProfileStatsScreen = (props) => {
  const { userId } = props.route.params;
  const { initialRoute, username } = props.route.params;

  const RatingsDetails = () => <RatingsTab userId={userId} />;
  const FollowersDetails = () => <FollowersTab userId={userId} />;
  const FollowingsDetails = () => <FollowingsTab userId={userId} />;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title={username} />
      <TopTabContainer initialRouteName={initialRoute}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Ratings"
          component={RatingsDetails}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: "Reviews" }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Followers"
          component={FollowersDetails}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: "Followers" }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Following"
          component={FollowingsDetails}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: "Followings" }}
        />
      </TopTabContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

TAB COMPONENT (RATINGS)

```
export const RatingsTab = ({ userId }) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      axios
        .get(`${process.env.BASE_ENDPOINT}/users/${userId}/reviews`, {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user?.token}` },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setReviews(res.data.reviews);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          setLoading(false);
        });
      setLoading(false);
    }, [userId, user?.token])
  );

  const renderRatings = ({ item }) => {
    const { reviewer, rating, review, createdAt } = item;

    return (
      <CardRatings
        avatar={reviewer?.avatar}
        name={reviewer?.name}
        date={moment(createdAt).format("LL")}
        rating={rating}
        review={review}
        service={"Tuns"}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!loading && (
        <FlatList
          data={reviews}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item?._id}
          renderItem={renderRatings}
        />
      )}
      {loading && <Spinner />}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to the solution, your useFocusEffect is configured properly. Change the lines

```js
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      setLoading(true);
```

to read

```js
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      if (isLoading) return; 
      setLoading(true);
```

i.e., if loading is true, don't make the axios call. While this doesn't eliminate the possibility of extra requests, it should reduce what you're seeing by quite a bit.

Also, since you're using .then, wrap the final line of your callback in .finally.

```js
.finally(()=> {
  setLoading(false)
});
```

Otherwise, your loading state will be set to false before the promise resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but unfortunately is not working. Let's assume that i am already in the RatingsTab and i have the data because by far the request was already made. If i go to FollowersTab and after that i come back to RatingsTab i don't want to make call if the data has not changed. `if (isLoading) return;` i think it will not helping me, because the loading state is false at first (when the Ratings Tab component is re-created).

Comment: How will you know the data hasn't changed without making the call? This should also be a comment under my answer

Comment: Actually i don't know really :) For example, in apps like Instagram, Tik tok it works, they fetch the data just when they are changed (no matter if you are going to another tab).

Comment: In react navigation, i think it's related with the useFocusEffect function..but i think i miss something.

Comment: The common way of getting updated state without looking is by using sockets, which is a quite different strategy than you've implemented here. If you're doing it with REST calls, you would have to poll to get updated data, i.e. make the call every so often

Comment: I understand. thank you for your explanations :)

Comment: You should clarify your question rather than answering your question.

Comment: Basically i have a component parent (ProfileStatsScreen) which holds 3 screens/tabs (RatingsTab, FollowersTab, FollowingsTab). Well, if i will go to RatingsTab for the first time.. useEffect / useFocusEffect will be called and i will get the ratings. Then, if i will go to the next tab (FollowersTab)...and come back in Ratings Tab.. i do not want to fetch the ratings again if they are the same. Apps like Instagram or Tik tok, fetch the data just once following my example (even if you are switching the tabs)..I am looking for a solution. Hope it's clear..